# Access to $content['links'] from page.tpl.php in D7

Tags: nodes, theming, 7

I understand how to print node fields and custom fields in the page.tpl.php files but how would I go about adding the $content['links'], (or I suppose $content['comments'], but I am really just looking for the links) like it is in the node.tpl.php?

I took a look at the node object and I don't see it in there. I would like to ultimately have the node links printed in two places, and one of the places is easiest to access from the page.tpl.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it looks like it can be pulled off with (in the page.tpl.php files):

```
$links = node_view($node);
print render($links['links']);
```

Anyone know if there is a better approach?

Comment: This has a side-effect that hook_node_view will be called twice for each node visit. So that, it can be that the statistics, logs are not updated correctly.